# ASP.NET HTTPClient Get request status waiting for activation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a method that will return JSON data by making a GET request to a RestApi URL. When I run the application in debug mode, I get below data in response.

`Id = 337, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"`

Here is my code:

```
public class Methods
{
    public static async Task<JObject> Get(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        // client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        return new JObject { response.StatusCode };
    }
}
```

Here is my view where I am trying to access data:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Methods RestMethod = new Methods();
    var data = Methods.Get("http://url/products", "domain\userid", "Password");

    return View();
}
```

When I add debug in view at `var data = .....` thats where I am getting `waiting for activation`.

Any help is really appreciated. :)

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: Right, so you're not currently awaiting the task... bear in mind that `data` is the task, not the `JObject`.

Comment: hmm.. so I need to add `await` like this `var data = await Methods.Get()`?

Comment: I suspect so, yes - which will mean your `Index` method will need to be async as well.

Comment: What is IActionResult  here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use async/await you should do it starting from the calling entry point. Currently you call the `Get` method which returns a running task but you do not wait for it to be completed. The easiest fix is for your `Index` method code should be changed like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    // Methods RestMethod = new Methods();
    var data = await Methods.Get("http://url/products", "domain\userid", "Password");
    return View();
}
```

Also see [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more details on `async/await`, he has written extensively on on this subject and also well known pitfalls and patterns.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense now. :)